# Convergence of a sequence in $C^{\infty}_c(U)$ under limit topology

Tags: analysis, function-spaces

For an open $U \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$, we give $C^{\infty}_c(U)$ (smooth compactly supported complex-valued functions on $U$) the limit topology from the inclusions $C^{\infty}_K(U)$ over all compact sets $K \subset U$, where $C^{\infty}_K(U)$ is the space of smooth functions on $U$ with support contained in $K$ (given the topology of uniform convergence of the function and all its derivatives within $K$). So this means a subset $\Omega \subseteq C^{\infty}_c(U)$ is open iff $\Omega \cap C^{\infty}_K(U)$ is an open subset of $C^{\infty}_K(U)$ for all compact $K \subset U$.

It is a fact (stated e.g. in Mitrea's 'Distributions, Partial Differential Equations and Harmonic Analysis' page 550) that a sequence $f_j \in C^{\infty}_c(U)$ converges to some $f \in C^{\infty}_c(U)$ if and only if there exists some compact $K \subset U$ with all $f_j$'s and $f$ in $C^{\infty}_K(U)$, with $f_j \to f$ in $C^{\infty}_K(U)$. How does one prove this? Particularly I don't see why there should be a compact $K$ with all $f_j$'s contained in $C^{\infty}_K(U)$. I realize Rudin's Functional Analysis has a proof of this statement, but his definition of the topology is quite different (even though I assume it ends up the same topology) so it doesn't help me much.

Comment: The topology on that space is the directed limit topology. The statement you describe about convergence is a consequence of the structure of this topology where a countable increasing collection of spaces define the topology.

Comment: Yeah I suspected it might be true for a general $X = \cup X_n$ but wasn't sure if maybe one needs niceness assumptions on the $X_n$. What is the general argument like then?

Comment: As fari can’t remember all the details, but notice that the topology on each layer $X_n$ is given by uniform norms in $C^n$ on a relatively compact open set $\Omega_n$ and the sequence of omegas is increasing and cover the whole of the domain.

Comment: In fact, if $f$ is the limit of a sequence $f_n$ in this topology, the support of $f$ is in one on such $\Omega_n$, that explains more or less wky there is a common support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say that $U= \Bbb{R}^n$ because it works quite the same for any open set (replacing $|x_k|\to \infty$ by $d(x_k,\partial U)\to 0$)

If the $f_j$ are not supported on a common compact then there is a  strictly increasing sequence
$|x_k|\to \infty$ and $e_k$ such that $|f_{e_k}(x_k)|\ne 0$.

Take a strictly positive continuous function such that $$h(x_k)=\frac1{|f_{e_k}(x_k)|}$$ then $$V=\{ \phi \in C^\infty_c(U), \|h \phi\|_\infty < 1/2\}$$ is open and $(f_j-\psi)_{j\ge J}$  is not contained in $V$ for any $J\ge 1,\psi\in C^\infty(U)$ whence $f_j$ isn't Cauchy for your topology.

Comment: I believe you meant to write $\psi \in C^{\infty}_c(U)$? Also, is there any particular reason you used $\| h \phi\|_{\infty} < 1/2$ instead of, say, $ < 1$?

Comment: I took $\psi\in C^\infty(U)$ because you'll want to show your topological space is complete. For most $j,k, f_j(x_k)-\psi(x_k) = \psi(x_k)$ so you need $|\psi(x_k)|< |f_{e_k}(x_k)|/ 2$ for $k$ large enough but then  $f_{e_k}-\psi$ won't be in $V$

Comment: I just wanted to understand convergence of sequences anyway. So we can't have $f_j \to f$ because then we'd have $f_j - f \to 0$ and so eventually $f_j - f$ would lie in $V$, but it can't because, multiplying by $h$, the $hf_j$ term will be $1$ arbitrary close to the boundary, and the $hf$ term is harmless since $f$ has compact support.

Comment: Yes but it works as well when assuming the limit is just smooth or continuous, ie. your space is complete, and so it is the good choice of topology on $C^\infty_c$